npm ERESOLVE could not resolve ESLint-related packages
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: eslint-plugin-unused-imports@3.2.0
npm error Found: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0
npm error node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm error   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm error   node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm error     eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm error     node_modules/react-scripts
npm error       react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm error   peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-jest@25.7.0
npm error   node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest
npm error     eslint-plugin-jest@"^25.3.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm error     node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm error       eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm error       node_modules/react-scripts
npm error         react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"6 - 7" from eslint-plugin-unused-imports@3.2.0
npm error node_modules/eslint-plugin-unused-imports
npm error   dev eslint-plugin-unused-imports@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.13.1
npm error node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm error   peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"6 - 7" from eslint-plugin-unused-imports@3.2.0
npm error   node_modules/eslint-plugin-unused-imports
npm error     dev eslint-plugin-unused-imports@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

My dev dependencies inside the package.json are shown below:
   "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.24.7",
      "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.24.7",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow": "^7.24.7",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.24.7",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
      "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
      "eslint": "^8.55.0",
      "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
      "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
      "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-perfectionist": "^2.5.0",
      "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
      "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
      "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.0.0",
      "prettier": "^3.1.0",
      "typescript": "^5.4.5",
      "typescript-eslint": "^7.13.1"
   },
   "overrides": {
      "nth-check": "2.1.1",
      "react-scripts": {
         "typescript": "^5"
      }
   },

I know this is a conflict among ESLint-related packages but I don't want to use the --force or --legacy-peer-deps.
I want a clean install with the correct packages but I am a little bit confused about the root of the problem and what causes this.
Any recommendations?

Stop using react-scripts. Or use the versions of dependencies it is expecting.

@jonrsharpe it's a legacy project, this is not an option.

So use the legacy dependency versions. Or --force it (but note something might break). The error tells you what the problem is - that's not an internally consistent dependency tree.

@jonrsharpe that might break my dependencies.

...yes? That's why it's complaining at you. It cannot guarantee what you're asking for is actually OK.

@jonrsharpe From my understanding eslint-plugin-unused-imports@3.2.0 found @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0 and at the same time @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1 ? That's why the conflict? If so, what is the correct library that I should keep?

It seems I have to call every time npm install --legacy-peer-deps. No upstream dependency conflict solution was found.
